# XSL taking subnodes of selected nodes with template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML where there are n number of nodes of GRTSource under GRTReport. I want only first 5 nodes of GRTSource and I want to access details of tables irrespective of table being the immidiate child or not.

Here is demo file:

```
<GRTReport>
<GRTSource>
        <title>Unified CM Cluster Name</title>
        <comment>Lists the cluster name from the Enterprise Parameter and the publisher server name/IP.</comment>
        <title></title>
        <comment></comment>
        <table summary='Cluster Information'>
            <row>
                <cell style='header'>Cluster Name</cell>
                <cell style='header'>Publisher Name/IP</cell>
            </row>
            <row>
                <cell>xyzw</cell>
                <cell>xyz1234</cell>
            </row>
        </table>
    </GRTSource>
    <GRTSource>
        <div>
        <title>Unified CM Cluster Name</title>
        <comment>Lists the cluster name from the Enterprise Parameter and the publisher server name/IP.</comment>
        <title></title>
        <comment></comment>
        <table summary='Cluster Information'>
            <row>
                <cell style='header'>Cluster Name</cell>
                <cell style='header'>Publisher Name/IP</cell>
            </row>
            <row>
                <cell>xyzw</cell>
                <cell>xyz1234</cell>
            </row>
        </table>
    </div>
    </GRTSource>
    </GRTReport>
```

Here is my xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>  
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GRTReport/GRTSource[position() &lt; 6]">

        <fieldset class="reportSourceFieldset">
            <legend>
                <xsl:value-of select="title[1]"/>
            </legend>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::table"/>
        </fieldset>
        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <table class="reportData">
            <tr class="cuesTableBg">    
                <xsl:for-each select="row[position() = 1]/cell">
                    <th>
                        <pre>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                        </pre>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="row[position() &gt; 1]">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current()[contains(@style,'fixedFormat')]">
                        <td>
                            <pre><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></pre>
                        </td>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td>
                        <span>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/></span>
                        </td>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
```

Somehow it is taking GRTSources of count upto 5 but the query is accepting tables outside the GRSource count of 5 as well. It is infact considering all the tables on the page and not just inside top-5 GRTSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>  
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

you are applying templates indiscriminately to **all** children of the current node (in this case, the root node). The [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) "allow recursive processing to continue in the absence of a successful pattern match by an explicit template rule in the stylesheet". This means that templates are applied from here to `<GRTReport>`, and from there to the `<GRTSource>` elements that were not matched previously by the more explicit rule, and from there to their children - and suddenly you have an expicit template rule that matches.

Try changing the above to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>  
                <xsl:apply-templates select="GRTReport/GRTSource[position() &lt; 6]"/>
            </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you can change this:

```
<xsl:template match="GRTReport/GRTSource[position() &lt; 6]">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="GRTReport/GRTSource">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to consider:

```
<xsl:template match="GRTReport/GRTSource">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::GRTSource) + 1 &lt; 6">
                <fieldset class="reportSourceFieldset">
                    <legend>
                        <xsl:value-of select="descendant::title[1]"/>
                    </legend>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::table"/>
                </fieldset>
                <br />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's possible but not recommendable due to duplication inside the two templates. Better: Use one `<xsl:template match="GRTReport/GRTSource">` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="GRTSource[position() &lt; 6]">`/`<xsl:apply-templates select="GRTSource[position() &gt;= 6]">`, respectively.

Comment: @Tomalak, Is the modified template okay?

Comment: No, that's the same thing: You would *still* need a second template to output `<GRTSource>` elements after position 5. That's a repetitive and unclean approach. -- Use a single template that can output `<GRTSource>` elements. It must not care about their position. Then use `<xsl:apply-templates>` to output only those elements that you want to see.